# Rails Graphql Mutations Dynamic Arguments Required Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

In Graphql Mutation, what I am trying to do is set the value of required option dynamically based on another argument's presence. I am not sure if it's possible or not.

For Example:

```
class Mutations::CreateAuthor < Mutations::BaseMutation
  description "Creates Author#{attr}"

  argument :name, String, required: false
  argument :email, String, required: true
  **argument :phone, String, required: proc { |attr| !attr.email.present? }**
  //Trying to set required value dynamically based on other argument

  field :author, Types::AuthorType, null: false
  field :errors, [String], null: false

  def resolve(name:, email:)
    author = Author.new(name: name, email: email)
    if author.save
      {author: author, errors: []}
    else
      {author: [], errors: author.errors.full_messages}
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this declaratively. Probably the simplest way to handle this is to add a `ready?` method. For example:

```
def ready?(name:, email:, phone:)
  if !email && !phone
    return false, { errors: ["Phone is required when email is not provided"]}
  else
    true
  end
end
```